# Matching charset of HTTP Header Content-Type

Tags: javascript, regex

In JavaScript, I want to get "charset" attribute of the HTTP header field name 'Content-Type'

The Regex I've seen thus far has been something like:

```
var charset = (/^charset=(.+)/im).exec(ContentType)[1];
```

With *ContentType* contain informations of Content-Type HTTP header.

But in my testing, the matched result is 'null'

**Edit:** follow response to @andris leduskrasts, I do this

```
var ctype = 'text/html; charset=utf-8';
var charset = new RegExp('charset=.*?(?=$|\s|\;|\")').exec(ctype);
system.stdout.writeLine(charset);
```

I get 'charset=utf-8'. But some idea to get only 'utf-8'. ?

Comment: How does the string you are working with look like?

Comment: for charset of http have a look at this page http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.2

Comment: @andris leduskrasts, string look like this 
text/html; charset=utf-8
or
charset=utf-8; text/html
or
charset=utf-8

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just experienced the same problem.

If you need to extract just the charset value from an arbitrary content-type header (which permits characters after the charset assignment as per [rfc1341](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html)) you can use the following JS regexp:

```
var re = /charset=([^()<>@,;:\"/[\]?.=\s]*)/i;
```

This works because the matched group starts after `=` and excludes the possible endings of the charset specification given in the link; namely `()<>@,;:\"/[]?.=`, spaces, and (implicitly) end-of-string.

Since the charset is optional, you can set an appropriate value with something like:

```
var charset = re.test(ctype) ? re.exec(ctype)[1] : 'utf8';
```

or some other default.

Answer (score 3):

If you're fine with the "`charset=`" part being a part of your result, this will do:

`charset=.*?(?=\s|\;|\|$")`

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1">` results in `charset=ISO-8859-1`.

If you want to get rid of the "`charset=`" part already in the regex, it's a bit more tricky, as javascript doesn't support lookbehinds.

EDIT:

If you want only the UTF-8 part, it's easily doable IF your variable is always the content type and, hence, it ends with the actual charset. In this case: `[^\s\;\=]*?(?=$)` ; which will really just select the last word of your string, after a space, a semicolon and a `=`. This is by no means a good solution for finding the charset in a random string, but it might do the trick for your particular case.

Comment: OK. I update my post to add $. But is possible to obtain 'utf-8' ?

Comment: Yes It' always the contenttype of the HTTP header.field 'Content-Type" .

Comment: Check out the edit, it may work for your case, although it no longer has anything to do with finding the actual charset.

Answer (score 3):

This Javascript library, do the job !

[content-type](https://github.com/jshttp/content-type) : Create and parse HTTP Content-Type header according to RFC 7231

```
var contentType = require('content-type')
var obj = contentType.parse('image/svg+xml; charset=utf-8')
```

Parse a content type string. This will return an object with the following properties (examples are shown for the string '`image/svg+xml; charset=utf-8`'):

- `type`: The media type (the type and subtype, always lower case).
  Example: 'image/svg+xml'
- `parameters`: An object of the parameters in the media type (name of
  parameter always lower case). Example: `{charset: 'utf-8'}`

Throws a `TypeError` if the string is missing or invalid.